# How can solvePnPRansac be used with double values?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV's [`solvePnPRansac()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnpransac) to compute the 3D pose from a known 2D projection of the object. My values (intrinsic camera parameters, model points (3D), image points (2D)) are all double values. The normal `solvePnP()` does not complain about that.

However, when I try to use solvePnPRansac, it yields an error message:

> Assertion failed < opoints.depth() == CV_32F >

How can I use this function with double values? (working with float does not give the desired results)

Comment: The documentation for both functions specifies that they take cv::Point2f/3f.  I don't know how you can get around that short of changing the source code yourself.  You really need that many digits of precision?  The fact that you are using Ransac suggests you have some noise in your data which would imply that double precision is overkill.

Comment: Good point. The main motivation why I'd like to get the Ransac version working is that the normal solvePnP() gives visually fine results with double values but not with float values (visually = when I use the reported rotation and translation to compute the back-projection), but somehow the rotation matrix seems to be "wrong" as it is very different from the results when using the POSIT algorithm.

Comment: How thoroughly have you tested the "wrong" behavior when using floats?  When using an algorithm like this I like to test it by generating a set of 3d points, applying a known transformation and projection to get 2d points, and then feeding those points into the algorithm to see if it can re-create my transformation.  That lets you see exactly what error there is if any and to test your degrees of freedom 1 at a time.  That should give you a much better idea what exactly the problem is.  I am skeptical that the issue is using single precision.

Answer (score 2):

Today I have tested the SolvePnPRAnsac, for ITERATIVE AND P3P the results seems to be the same, but when I used these results to rendered my object, the redered image is very different from the current frame. 
In case of EPnP option, the translation vector is very similar to the ITERATIVE and P3P results but the rotation is very different from the other two options'. However the rendered image I got from Epnp result is very good, it seems like there some problem with P3P and ITERATIVE in implementation the algorithm.